# Derivation of Labor Function

Tags: mathematical-economics, labor-economics

I want to know if I'm taking the right steps to derive a labor equation from a utility function. Suppose $U(x,L)=x^{0.5}+l^{0.5}$ where $L$ is labor, $x$ is our one good of interest, and $l$ is leisure. We also have a budget constraint $px+wL=m+wT$. We begin with taking our partials and get our optimality condition:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{l}}}{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}}=\frac{p}{w} \Rightarrow x=\frac{w^2l}{p^2}.
\end{equation}
Next I plug this solution into our budget constraint. Here, $m$ is our non-labor income, $w$ our wage, $T$ our time endowment, and $p$ is the price of good $x$. Since I'm interested in the labor supply equation $L^{\ast}=T-l$, I solve for $l$.
\begin{align*}
p\left(\frac{w^2l}{p^2}\right)+wL=m+wT.
  \end{align*}
When we solve for $l$, we get
\begin{align*}
l=\frac{mp+pwT-pwL}{w^2}
  \end{align*}
Does this mean that the labor function in this instance is:
\begin{align*}
L^{\ast}=T-\frac{mp+pwT-pwL}{w^2}
  \end{align*}
I fear that I've made an error at some point.

Comment: Budget constraint is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the right direction, just not complete. You have $wl + pL = wmp + w^2pT$

$$\implies w(T-L) + pL = wmp + w^2pT \\ \implies L(p-w) = wmp + w^2pt-wT \\ \implies L^{*}(w,m,p,T) = \frac{wmp + w^2pT-wT}{p-w}$$

Comment: This is incorrect because budget constraint is incorrect. Another way to see that this is incorrect is because as $m$ (non-labor income) increases, the labor supply must not go up in this environment, but in your case labor supply is an increasing function of $m$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine the labor supply function, we need to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{l, L, x} & \ x^{0.5}+l^{0.5} \\ \text{s.t. } &  px \leq w(T-l) + m \\ \text{and} & \ L+l=T, \\ & l\geq 0, L\geq 0, x\geq 0\end{eqnarray*}

We can re-write the above problem as an optimization problem in two variables:
\begin{eqnarray*} \max_{l, x} & \ x^{0.5}+l^{0.5} \\ \text{s.t. } &  px +wl \leq wT + m \\ \text{and} & \ 0\leq l \leq T, x\geq 0\end{eqnarray*}

Solving the problem we get the following as demand for leisure $l$:
\begin{eqnarray*} l^d(p,w,m,T) = \min\left(\dfrac{p(wT+m)}{w(w+p)},T\right)\end{eqnarray*}
and therefore, labor supply is given by:
\begin{eqnarray*} L^s(p,w,m,T) = T-\min\left(\dfrac{p(wT+m)}{w(w+p)},T\right) = \max\left(\dfrac{Tw^2-pm}{w(w+p)},0\right)\end{eqnarray*}